# 4D array not exporting to .mat file

Tags: export

I am using Mma 9.0

I am trying to export an array with `Dimensions` {5,100,160,160} to a .mat-file using the `Export` command, but it is not working and I get the following error instead:

> Export::type: "{<<1>>} cannot be exported to the !(\"MAT\") format."

I have tried exporting `data[[i]]` separately, and then it works but then I am stuck with 5 separate files.

Why and what to do?

Comment: The problem arises in version 10.1 as well... clearly a bug which must get fixed.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork and rhermans: This is not a bug.  MAT4 does not support multidimensional arrays, only matrices.  Mathematica only exports to MAT4.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know the dimensions of the array when you are importing it back, the quickest solution is to Flatten the array before you export it as a MAT file, and then ArrayReshape it back when you want to use it.

```
testArray = Array[#1 + #2 - #3 - #4 &, {1, 1, 2, 2}]
(* {{{{0,-1},{-1,-2}}}} *)
Export["test.mat", testArray]
Export::type: {{{{0,-1},{-1,-2}}}} cannot be exported to the MAT format. >>
(* But you can flatten it *)
Export["test.mat", Flatten[testArray]]
(* "test.mat" *)
importedArray = ArrayReshape[Import["test.mat"], {1, 1, 2, 2}];
testArray == importedArray
(* True *)
```

Comment: That's a good advice. An improvement for robustness might be that the first few elements of the flattened array will describe its dimensions. i.e. `Flatten[{Depth[arr],Dimensions[arr],arr}]`.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a bug.**

Mathematica can only export to the version 4 MAT format, [as documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MAT.html).  This format [only supports *matrices*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html?refresh=true), but not 3 or higher dimensional arrays.

When trying to export a 3D array, Mathematica will in fact export *a list of matrices*, each of which will be assigned to a separate variable in MATLAB.  When passing a 4D array to `Export`, it will simply fail as this is an unsupported format, as the `Export::type` message indicates.

---

What can you do then?  That depends on *why* you want a MAT format in the first place.  If it's because you need to use it in some software *other than MATLAB*, then just try a different format.  If that software only supports MAT version 6 files, and you have no access to MATLAB, then you are out of luck.

If you just want to send the data to MATLAB, then use [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) or export to [HDF5](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html) instead. MATLAB's own v7.3 MAT files are in fact HDF5 files with a specific structure.